# How to change the X axis of the axes using matplotlib in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to change the X axis of the axes from "2017-01" to "2017-12".

But, I couldn't make it.

Here is a dataset I use.

```
df_daily.groupby(["Date"])[["Track Name"]].head(1)
```

[image]

Datetime of the index and Date of the column are same value.

The value of date is between "2017-01-01" to "2017-12-31".

Here is a code and outcome.

```
df_for_extracting_song = df_daily[(df_daily["Artist"] == "Ed Sheeran") & (df_daily["Region"] == "global") & (df_daily["Position"] <= 100) & (df_daily["Date"] <= "2017-12-31")]
df_ed_sheeran = df_for_extracting_song.groupby(['Track Name']).size()
df_ed_sheeran = df_ed_sheeran.reset_index()
df_ed_sheeran = df_ed_sheeran[df_ed_sheeran[0] >= 20]
df_ed_sheeran = df_ed_sheeran.set_index("Track Name")
df_ed_sheeran = df_for_extracting_song[df_for_extracting_song['Track Name'].isin(df_ed_sheeran.index)]
df_ed_sheeran = df_ed_sheeran.reset_index()
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="Date", y="Position", data=df_ed_sheeran, hue="Track Name")
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0, fontsize=18)
```

[image]

The problems is the xaxis of xaxes is blacked by a lot of labels of date.

I have to get rid of it and set twelve months properly.

How can I make it?

I will appreciate it if you help me out.

Comment: Your "Dates" are strings. You would want to convert them to actual dates e.g. via `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])`, then the axes should be labelled automatically.

Comment: Thank you for telling me. I tried what you said, but it didn't work out. I put a post where I am now. Please tell me if you could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a locator and formatter for the xaxis.

```
import matplotlib.dates as md

months = md.MonthLocator()
month_fmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(month_fmt)
```

A common solution to overlapping labels on the xaxis is to rotate them also.

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
```

ha stands for horizontal alignment, in this case the tick mark will be to the right of the label

**Edit:** I should've mentioned that this will only work if your index is of type datetime. It was hard to tell whether or not your had a datetime index with some of the wording used in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much for telling me so early! I will try it!

Comment: Thank you for telling me. I tried what you said, but it didn't work out. I put a post where I am now. Please tell me if you could help me out.

Comment: What you call "2." in your answer looks correct to me. I cannot test why it won't work because I cannot run the code.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate what you did.

Comment: What is the max and min datetime for the data you're looking at? It looks like you're trying to plot data spanning years from 2001 to 2017. If you use month locator there it would still be trying to plot 216 months(x ticks) and would still cause overlap. You should limit the index to the span of time you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help.

I tried two following things.

1.

```
import matplotlib.dates as md

df_for_extracting_song = df_daily[(df_daily["Artist"] == "Ed Sheeran") & (df_daily["Region"] == "global") & (df_daily["Position"] <= 100) & (df_daily["Date"] <= "2017-12-31")]
df_ed_sheeran = df_for_extracting_song.groupby(['Track Name']).size()
df_ed_sheeran = df_ed_sheeran.reset_index()
df_ed_sheeran = df_ed_sheeran[df_ed_sheeran[0] >= 20]
df_ed_sheeran = df_ed_sheeran.set_index("Track Name")
df_ed_sheeran = df_for_extracting_song[df_for_extracting_song['Track Name'].isin(df_ed_sheeran.index)]
df_ed_sheeran = df_ed_sheeran.reset_index()

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="Datetime", y="Position", data=df_ed_sheeran, hue="Track Name")
months = md.MonthLocator()
month_fmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(month_fmt)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0, fontsize=18)
```

[image]

There were two problems. The outcome appeared the right side and xaxis was blacked.

2.

```
import matplotlib.dates as md

df_for_extracting_song = df_daily[(df_daily["Artist"] == "Ed Sheeran") & (df_daily["Region"] == "global") & (df_daily["Position"] <= 100) & (df_daily["Date"] <= "2017-12-31")]
df_ed_sheeran = df_for_extracting_song.groupby(['Track Name']).size()
df_ed_sheeran = df_ed_sheeran.reset_index()
df_ed_sheeran = df_ed_sheeran[df_ed_sheeran[0] >= 20]
df_ed_sheeran = df_ed_sheeran.set_index("Track Name")
df_ed_sheeran = df_for_extracting_song[df_for_extracting_song['Track Name'].isin(df_ed_sheeran.index)]
df_ed_sheeran = df_ed_sheeran.reset_index()

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="Datetime", y="Position", data=df_ed_sheeran, hue="Track Name")
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0, fontsize=18)
```

[image]

There were two problems. The outcome appeared the right side and xaxis was not months.

[image]

Dtypes of Datetime is "datetime64".